# Docker and Kubernetes repository for linux

Tags: linux, docker, containers, kubernetes

I have been trying to do a Docker and Kubernetes setup on Linux on aws but I am unable to do the same.

```
yum install -y docker docker-registry etcd kubernetes flannel
Loaded plugins: amazon-id, rhui-lb, search-disabled-repos
No package docker available.
No package docker-registry available.
No package kubernetes available.
No package flannel available.
```

Can anyone suggest a common repo and set of repos that i need to add to get this setup done?

Note: Subscription manager isnt an option as this servers are provisioned via AWS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try installing using this command instead of `sudo yum`

```
curl -sSL https://get.docker.com/ | sh
```